# Enable a ctor if each argument is convertible to a specific type

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, enable-if

I want to enable a ctor of a class `foo` whenever there is more than one argument and each argument is convertible to a type `value_type`. I've tried the following:

```
struct foo
{
    using value_type = /* some type */;

    template<class... Ts,
        std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Ts) > 0) && std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible_v<Ts, value_type>...>, int> = 0>
    explicit foo(Ts&&... vs)
    {
    }
};
```

Suppose `foo::value_type = float`. I've tried to declare `foo bar{ 1 };` and observed that the ctor is disabled. In order to see what's going on, I've removed the `std::conjunction_v` part from the template and added

```
static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible_v<Ts, value_type>...>, "");
```

to the body. Now my compiler (MSVC 14.1 / Clang) yields the error

> template argument for template type parameter must be a type

at

```
static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible_v<Ts, value_type>...>, "");               
                             // ^
```

What exactly is the problem here?c

Comment: Note that `std::conjunction` offers short-circuiting. It can't do that if you've already instantiated everything before giving it to `std::conjunction`.

Comment: A c++17 solution - `enable_if_t<(is_convertible_v<Ts, value_type> && ... && true), int> = 0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is exactly as stated, *template argument for template type parameter must be a type*. In `std::conjunction<T...>`, the `T`s are supposed by be types, but `std::is_convertible_v<X, Y>` produces values directly.

Try this instead:

```
std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<Ts, value_type>...>
//                                    ^ no `_v`.
```

---

BTW, since you are targeting C++17, you could use [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) instead of `std::conjunction`:

```
template<class... Ts,
  std::enable_if_t<((sizeof...(Ts) > 0) && ... && std::is_convertible_v<Ts, value_type>), int> _ = 0
>
```